# Objective-C: Why this function name caused a warning?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4

This is the original header file:

```
@interface TestDataHelper : NSObject {



}
+(void) populateTestData:(NSManagedObjectContext*) managedObjectContext;

+(void) testPopulateTestData:(NSManagedObjectContext*) managedObjectContext;

@end
```

When I compile this file, I got this warning:

`method definiton not found`

for testPopulateTestData

When I ignore the warning and run the app in iphone simulator, I got a runtime exception:

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[TestDataHelper testPopulateTestData:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x104d8'`

Rename the method to 'test' alone seems to solve the problem

What is special about `testXXX` method name?

**EDIT:** implementation is there and done. Renaming the method name (in both .h and .m) removes the warning, and the final app works.

**EDIT 2**:

Here is the implementation of the function `test` (originally named as `testPopulatedTestData`):

```
+(void) test:(NSManagedObjectContext*) managedObjectContext {

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Stock" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    [sortDescriptors release];
    [sortDescriptor release];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];

    NSEnumerator *e = [mutableFetchResults objectEnumerator];
    id object;
    while (object = [e nextObject]) {
        // do something with object
        Stock* fc = (Stock*) object; 
        NSLog(@"get a fc %s", [[fc name] description]);
    }

}
```

Comment: You have the interface, but is there a (valid) implementation?

Comment: Where is the implementation file?

Comment: @Anthony: You need to show us what the actual implementation is, not just tell us you have it.

Comment: It looks like you declared the method as `testPopulateTestData` but defined it as `testPopulatedTestData` -- note the extra 'd' in the implemented method name.  That would solve the issue if it's not just a copy-paste error.

Comment: @Richard: I will double check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is telling you that you've declared a method in your header file that you never implemented anywhere. The runtime error is telling you the same thing - you've sent the selector `testPopulateTestData` to the class `TestDataHelper` but it was never implemented.